How do I get an Rscript to run in Powershell?
I am trying to run an R script in a batch format. I have tried both R CMD BATCH and RSCRIPT and neither of them are working. I have added both the r.exe and rscript.exe to my PATH but I keep on getting errors that Powershell is saying that it doesn't recognize R or Rscript as cmdlets.
R CMD BATCH Particle_Classification.R
and
Rscript Particle_Classification.R
and
Rscript -e "print('hello StrikerRUS and jameslamb')"
All give me the same error
"Rscript: The term 'Rscript' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, s
cript file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path
is correct and try again."
Both executables are in my PATH or environment variables

I suspect something is going on so they're not actually in your path. Can you navigate to the folder with Rscript.exe in and run ./Rscript -e "print('does this work')"? If it does then the issue is with your path - if you have actually added them properly then possibly you need to restart your shell.

What is the output of $Env:Path -split ';'? Putting an executable into an environment variable will not cause it to be found for execution.

@SamR So i navigated to the folder with Rscript.exe and it ran and produced the the words. However when I am not in that folder it doesn't work.

@lit when i ran your command it produced the a bunch of lines but it did include the following
C:\Program Files\R\R-4.3.3\bin\x64\Rscript.exe
C:\Program Files\R\R-4.3.3\bin\x64\R.exe

@BrandonTitensor remove the executable from end of the path. You just want it to point to the folder,  i e. "C:\Program Files\R\R-4.3.3\bin\x64\"

As others have said, %PATH% should have a semi-colon-delimited list of directories, not executables. The suggestion that %PATH% includes paths to executables makes readers more suspicious that %PATH% is the cause of the problem. You commented to SamR that R.exe runs if you're in the "R-4.3.3\bin" directory. Does it run if you use the full path name and a different working directory?
